# How do I know if I am flagging correctly?

Tags: discussion, flags, flag-weight, flag-history

Is there any way to know how useful are the flags of a user? I read that *flagging - weights used to exist* (were visible) before, which would indicate this. However, what indicator is there now?

Is percentage of accepted flags a good measure of useful flagging, so to say? If yes, then what percentage would indicate that a user is flagging correctly or in a useful way?

<sub>I am asking about interpreting the numbers in terms of how useful you are. Is a 80% good or a 90% good? Or does the percentage even matter?</sub>

---

[This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144031/good-ratio-of-helpful-declined-flags) contains some explanation regarding the issue.

Comment: Flag weight used to be there but now [helpful flags](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/200868) is displayed on your profile.

Comment: And it is only visible to you. There is currently no way for you to get this information on another user (unless they choose to make it public).

Comment: Why would you need to know how helpful the flags of another user are?

Comment: With respect to your own flags, what percentage of helpful flags is a useful rate, for the improvement of the site ?

Comment: see: [How to read the flagging summary?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/85153/165773)

Comment: @gnat I understand what the numbers say, i am asking about interpreting the numbers in terms of how useful you. Is a 80% good or a 90% good ? Or does the percentage even matter ?

Comment: @AshRj this is explained in **[flag-weight tag wiki](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/flag-weight/info)** _"a measure of how well a user raises flags. Users with a history of flagging helpfully — as judged by moderators who act on those flags — earn high flag weight, and vice versa.."_

Comment: Since flag weight is not used anymore, number of helpful flags determines how high (or low) your flag is displayed in the moderator's flag queue. There is no good or bad rate.

Comment: ... _'Speculations about the formula are in [What's the flag weight formula in the 500-750 range?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83530/whats-the-flag-weight-formula-in-the-500-750-range) The rationale is basically "with greater power comes greater responsibility." Once you're established as a good flagger, another good flag doesn't provide much more information about how good a flagger you are.'_ (quoted from [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/101496/165773))

Comment: possible duplicate of [Good ratio of helpful / declined flags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144031/good-ratio-of-helpful-declined-flags)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Flag weight used to be there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/119709/166025) but now **helpful flags** link is displayed on your profile which is [private](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/200868). This flag summary page displays your flagging history. On the left side it also shows flagging summary (sample screenshot given below).

[image]

As such there is no rate against which you can compare your flagging effectiveness. The higher the number in front of **deemed helpful** the better, meaning you are flagging correctly in a useful manner.

If there are too many declined flags then your flags may not appear in the moderators' flag queue.

[Ben Brocka](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/166936/ben-brocka) [posted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135116/166025):

> The threshold should be: (helpful+10)-(declined)>=0
>
> So if I have 1 helpful flag and 11 declined flags (in that order) my
> flags will be suppressed. That's the only "bad thing" aside from flags
> appearing in lower priority in the Queue (irrelevant for non-SO
> sites).

Comment: I had 5 helpful ones and 3 declined ones. So am I allowed to continue flagging posts? I am currently suspended from flagging with this record by the way.

Comment: @PythonMaster Latest logic related to flagging suspension is mentioned in this post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/175405/

Answer (score 1):

There are no statistics, but I think as long as the number of rejected flags are less than 5% you are doing fine (although moderators may disagree on this).

If you have a high number of rejected flags you might change your flagging strategy. Try to focus on quality not on quantity.

Comment: That's actually not a bad example percentage once someone has over 100 or so flags. If we see someone _continuously_ flagging incorrectly, we'll typically decline one (or more) of the erroneous flags with a custom message telling them specifically what they're doing wrong. If it persists, we may contact them privately to discuss it (via chat, or other venues available to us).

Comment: "or other venues available to us" ... why does this sound as if some wrong-flaggers could suddenly get visits from big, brutish guys with unfriendly faces?