# Flagged post stats?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flags

This isn't really needed, it's just a curiosity.

I'd like to see some stats on flagged posts and their acceptance rates. For instance, of my 142 reviewed flags, I have 1 declined and 5 disputed. Among many things I'd like to know:

- What is the acceptance percentage for flags?
- What is the average number of flags per user?
- How does the number of flags compare plotted against reputation (as logarithmic?)

Like I say, mostly trivial, and solely a curiosity. (It is worth noting that there is no flag field in the Data Explorer.)

Comment: Not exactly what you are looking for, but related http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157555/how-do-i-know-if-i-am-flagging-correctly