# What Percentage is considered a good flagging history standard?

Tags: discussion, flags, flag-history

What would be a good standard for helpful flags? If 95%+ of your flags are deemed helpful is that good? or should it be higher?

Comment: I don't think there is a "good" percentage or ratio, but what I can tell you about your flags is that you have nothing to worry about.

Comment: Nice question. I would also like to know how to treat "disputed" flags in that regard?

Comment: @Shai: Disputed flags usually don't matter.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn - I think what we would like to know here is what is the "normal" SO user distribution of flags: how many are deemed helpful, how many are disputed and how many are declined.

Comment: @Shai That's somewhat of a different question (but can probably be covered in the same answer) - a good / acceptable ratio is not necessarily (and is fairly unlikely to be) exactly the same as what ratio people actually get.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn I think what HankyPanky (and myself) would like to know: are we helping moderating SO, or are we "making noise"? That is, are we flagging the right way, or do we raise too many flags that only make "noise" and disturb SO moderation processes? For that matter I think "disputed" flags do matter.

Comment: AFAIK, you don't get banned for too many disputed flags. Your total number of available flags are reduced for denied flags.

Comment: Well yeah, if a huge proportion of your flags is getting disputed then you should definitely take a look at how you're flagging things. Otherwise, the occasional flag dispute is harmless really.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn - you say "if a huge portion of your flags is getting disputed..." -- this question is exactly about this: What is conisdered a "huge portion"? 10%? 20%? 95%? I think we would like to have some reference as to what is considered "acceptble". I believe 1 out of 8 flags I raised is end up declined or disputed (only 6 out of 8 are helpful) - is that considered "normal"?

Comment: @Shai 6 / 8 will be too poor a standard I think, that's only 75% accepts. For me personally anything below 95% and I would be changing the way how I go about flagging.

Comment: 95% is way too low. Making a mistake is completely unacceptable. We'll accept nothing less than 100%. Oh, no, wait... I forget that we're only human sometimes.

Comment: But do we need to consider the disputed flags into account? I've read [this answer regarding the disputed flags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/95277/216721) and it really doesn't mean that the flag was not helpful. This would create quite a bit of stir as to what kinds of disputed flags should be taken into account and what types shouldn't. But wait, there's no classification as such. What do we do in such a case?!

Comment: see also: [Good ratio of helpful / declined flags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144031/good-ratio-of-helpful-declined-flags)

Comment: @gnat Neither of those give explicit statistics. Out of interest, I'd like a "x% is considered good, y% is considered acceptable, z% is what SO (SU, SF, P, CS, etc) users get".